# Maximising separation of $n$ variables with interval constraints

Tags: optimization, algorithms

**Problem**:

I have a set of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ (large integers): $[d_1^-,d_1^+],[d_2^-,d_2^+],...,[d_n^-,d_n^+]$. The intervals may overlap.

My goal is to find one value $x_i$ in each interval so that the values $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$ are the most spaced as possible. By most spaced I mean that the distances between consecutive $x_i$ in increasing value order are the greatest.

Another formulation is probably that the interval length between two consecutive $x_i$ are as close as possible from each other, while complying with the constraints.

A simple solution can be found when all the intervals are the same $[d^-,d^+]$. In this case the solution is a simple interpolation between $d^-$ and $d^+$: $(d^-, d^-+ \tfrac{d^+-d^-}{n - 1}, d^- + \tfrac{2(d^+-d^-)}{n - 1}, ...,d^- + \tfrac{(n-2)(d^+-d^-)}{n - 1}, d^+)$

But as soon as constraints are added, it gets more complicated: [image: Adding constraint]

**Lead on a solution**:

The best solution is found so far is to convert the problem into a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n => \mathbb{R}$ to maximize.

The function I use is the sum of distances between consecutive $x_i$. It can be formulated as $\sum_{i=2}^{n}d(s_i,s_{i-1})$ where $(s_1,...,s_n)$ is the sorted values from lowest to highest of $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$.

The distance $d$ must be a function that put apart values as much as possible, such as $d(a,b)=\sqrt{|a-b|}$ or $d(a,b)=log(|a-b|+1)$. Distances like $|a-b|$ or $|a-b|^2$ don't work as they try to create one very large interval and minimize the others.

Because of the sort, the function $f$ is not differentiable when $x_i$ are crossing. Some optimizers (I used a couple in Java from apache math) seem to handle the function quite well, but others just don't work.

However I'm not sure that they will always converge to the optimal solution. It also seem a bit overkill to use an optimizer to solve such problem. I'm sure that there are simpler and more effective solutions, but I didn't find any yet.